# Deny application access to hard drive or volume in Windows 7+

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

I want to deny some of the applications on my computer to access certain drives or logical volumes, but couldn't find a solution so far.

Background: My PC has an SSD as system drive and a 15TB Raid-6 w/ five harddrives. The controller is configured to spin down the drives after ~10-15 minutes. This is fine since sometimes I don't need to access anything on the Raid for a couple of hours or even longer. Some applications such as Adobe Reader access all logical volumes when starting for some reason I cannot comprehend. My assumption is that all volumes with a drive letter assigned are affected. Removing the letters and re-assigning them isn't an option at all ;)

How can I restrict Adobe Reader or other applications from accessing these volumes my Raid hosts?

Comment: I do not know how to disable access for certain application. But I suspect, if there is a tool to deny access to SSD for some application, you will lose the ability to open files from that volumes. So in this case it is better to try to find out what function makes Adobe Reader to read/write something from/to SSD. Look at the "recent files" feature. Maybe it checks their availability each time.

Comment: I want to restrict access to the Raid, not to the SSD. In fact, there is nothing on any volume on the Raid, that is of any use to Adobe Reader on my computer. So, yes, in my case I explicitely want to lose the ability to access anything from within Adobe Reader what is not on the SSD. You might be correct about the "recent files"-feature though (although in this case there aren't any recent files coming from those volumes).

Comment: What about a radical solution such as using another PDF viewer? This does not solve problems with other apps but as I understand the Adobe Reader is most annoying thing for you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software

Comment: Yes, it's the most annoying application :) I was hoping there might be a built-in solution to that problem since denying internet access via the Windows firewall works fine for other programs.

Comment: Have you considered running Reader as a separate user which doesn't have access to those volumes?

Comment: @TWiStErRob: that would be an option; however, I am not sure how to change the general application shortcut to include a "runas"-directive, so that every call to Adobe Reader would result in running as that restricted user.

Comment: You can try changing the pdf file association to run something like http://superuser.com/questions/124445 instead of reader.exe directly.

Comment: Be aware that "Adobe’s e-book reader sends your reading logs back to Adobe" [http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/10/adobes-e-book-reader-sends-your-reading-logs-back-to-adobe-in-plain-text/]. Ostensibly this is to catalog your documents in the cloud, not for DRM purposes. So the Adobe application checking all drives may be building a catalog. As mentioned, you might try Sumatra, Nitro or other free PDF reader.

Comment: I was also thinking to suggest running the viewer as a user that has been denied access to the drives. I'm thinking though, that since the disk has to be read to get the access control list, it will spin up anyway :(

Comment: would running the application in a virtual environment and not directly on the host system be a viable solution?

Answer (score 7):

In Windows, there is no native supported way to block certain processes from accessing certain drives, that goes "against the current nature" how the operating system handles drive access.

The right for access is determined by the logged on user's rights who starts the application. So if the software developer decided his software should search all accessible drives and does not give you the option to turn that off...  well, that's bad programming which does not consider your particular use case. But there are a few workarounds.

The only "sure" solution is 2, since the hardware virtualization layer (from the virtual machine) can block any applications to attempt to access the "real hardware" completely. Although I haven't had the case where solution 1 doesn't work, but theoretically I think it could be bypassed.

#### Option "1" - Disabling the drives at a "low level" - No additional software needed

**Option 1a**

It's possible to disable the volumes on a lower layer by disabling the drives altogether, but this will disable all volumes on the drive. Manually, you can do it by starting `diskmgmt.msc`, then right click on the drive and mark it "offline".

[image]

If needed, you should be able to do that using a command line script as well. It would be applied a similar way as Option 3a/b. You can do that, for example, via cmd as described [here](https://www.qualitestgroup.com/resources/knowledge-center/how-to-guide/offlineonline-disk-using-diskpart/) or via PowerShell, as it is described [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/48ea44b0-9962-49e3-95a1-568275851753/take-a-hdd-offlineonline).

**Option 1b**

You can deactivate the drive's driver altogether. To do in manually: start `diskmgmt.msc`, then right click, choose "options". Then go to the "Driver"-Tab and select "Deactivate". The drive will "disappear" in the disk manager and won't be accessible through the operating system anymore. Unless the software doesn't execute machine code commands to communicate directly with the hardware, there should be no way for the application to access the drives. At least as far as my knowledge of the ins and outs for operating systems goes.

[image]

If needed, you should be able to do that using a command line script as well. It would be applied a similar way as Option 3a/b using, for example, `Devcon.exe`. You can find a detailed description [here](https://superuser.com/a/431031/201818).

#### Option 2 - Using a virtual environment (mostly with 3rd party software)

If running the application within a virtual environment is an option at all, there are plenty of solutions out there:

- depending on your Windows version (Win7 and up required) and license ("Professional" required, "Home" won't do), you can just use Hyper-V to set up a virtual environment without any third party software.
- you can use a third party software to set up a virtual system like VMplayer, Virtual Box, etc. There are many freeware and payware alternatives. By using this solution, you will need a second licence for Windows (or you leave it unlicensed, but then you will get an overlay in the lower right corner of the screen that will tell you to register Windows). This will definitely prevent the software from accessing the drive.
- you could use a "sandbox"-application. But it will depend on the level of virualization the sandbox-application offers. In some cases, it can solve the problem; in other cases, it doesn't. Sandboxie, for example (the one harrymc describes in [his answer](https://superuser.com/a/1359811)), doesn't solve the problem with the configuration harrymc described in his (original) answer. Although the software might block the access, the drive will still spine up.  An alternative would be to use a different sandbox application like Cameyo, etc.

By the way, [here's a good article](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-safely-test-software-without-messing-up-your-sys-1680608496) for the main difference between the different virtualization software, especially the difference between a "whole" virtual machine (like Virtual Box) or "semi virtual" applications (like Sandboxie).

#### Option 3 - Unmounting just volumes (leaving the drive "intact") - No additional software needed, BUT it might not work in your case

**Option 3a**

Instead of starting the application via its regular shortcut, you could write a batch file using the command `mountvol` that first unmounts the unused volume, then starts the application, and then remounts the volume once the application doesn't access the drive anymore. The mounting/unmounting process via command line is described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/295913/how-to-mount-and-unmount-hard-drives-under-windows-the-unix-way) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/704870/mount-and-dismount-hard-drive-through-a-script-software). You can also use `diskpart` as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1191011/201818) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/842200/201818).

**Option 3b**

Alternatively, you could just leave the drive unmounted in general and mount it via a batch file that mounts the drive which you start manually when needed. After you're done using it, you can manually unmount it using a second batch file. You could automatize that by monitoring file system access requests and mount/unmount the drive as required following certain rules e.g. that certain applications won't have access. But I'm not sure automation is worth the extra effort involved.

#### Option 4 - Restricting access to a drive-letter (volume). Simple to do, but two small tools from Microsoft needed - BUT it might not work in your case

If you want to do it without 3rd party software but don't mind to use two small tools from Microsoft (if you don't use it already). I prefer this solution because it gets the problem "by the root" (differentiation between the user's and the application's rights) and it's fairly simple and no "big" third party software is needed.

Basically, you add a user with no access to the drive and then you start the program with those limited rights (you will still log on as your regular user, you won't use the restricted account to log on).

- Add a user account.
- Restrict the new user account's access to the drive by using Windows Access Control for the file system. Here's a good [How-To](https://softnuke.com/how-to-restrict-hard-drives-in-windows-7-for-user-accounts/) including screenshots.
- Then, start the software with those rights. You can, for example, use PsExec.exe to do that or Process Explorer, [here's how](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/easy-ways-run-windows-programs-restricted-rights.htm). One of those two you will have to download from the Microsoft website, if you don't have them already.

Answer (score 4):

I propose a solution that uses
[Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/).
I don't have your environment, so I have tested running `Acrobat.exe` in
a sandbox where its access to `D:` was blocked.
When opening in Acrobat the menu *File > Open*, I get this :

[image]

Notice that Acrobat can't even find the label of disk `D:`, so is forced to display
it in a lame way, and how it is blocked when I click on "Local Disk (D:)".

The steps I used were :

- Installed Sandboxie
- In Sandboxie Control, right-click the default sandbox and choose *Sandbox Settings*
- Open the branch of *Resource Access > File Access*, and click on *Blocked Access*
- Click *Add Program* and add Acrobat (mine was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe`)
- Click *Add* and add disk `D:`
- Click *OK*
- In Sandboxie Control, open the branch of *Program Start > Forced Folders*
- Click *Add Folder*
- Add the folder where resides Acrobat (mine was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat`)
- Click OK

From now on, all programs launching from the Acrobat folder are forced to
execute sandboxed, and specifically `Acrobat.exe` is blocked from
accessing the disk `D:`.
You might need to open up some other sandbox restrictions if Acrobat
will have some difficulties executing inside the sandbox.

I don't know if this will also block the specific Windows API call that Acrobat
uses to cause the wakeup of the disk, but might be worth trying.

Sandboxie is a great and versatile product that I recommend,
free for one default sandbox.
For multiple sandboxes it's payware, but life-time license price is very reasonable (I paid).
For example, I install products I test in a sandbox and can then wipe them
out with one click, and no need for an uninstaller.

---

Another isolation solution is by using Adobe Reader inside a
[Docker container](https://www.docker.com/).
Docker containers are small and work like a virtual machines, but without needing to create the machine, since ready-made containers are downloaded from the Docker gallery.

You may use
[Chocolatey](https://stefanscherer.github.io/get-started-with-docker-on-windows-using-chocolatey/)
as package manager.

Chocolatey has many available pre-built packages with Adobe Reader at
[Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 2018.011.20063](https://chocolatey.org/packages/adobereader).

With Docker, absolute isolation is possible as regarding resources,
and on the other hand one is able to share resources such as folders
in a completely native way.

Comment: @WackGet: Any comment ?

Comment: He says it doesn't work, the drive still does spin up, at least in his use case. I'm wondering, does Sandboxie give you the option to hide resources at the hardware layer? I haven't installed it yet.

Comment: @WackGet: Sandboxie has more settings available in its config files. But first: Do the disks wake up the moment Adobe is launched, or only when using the menu *File > Open*?

Comment: Besides the above question, I added another light-weight isolation option, by using Docker. Docker containers are small and work like a virtual machines, but without needing to create it, since containers are ready-made and are downloaded from the Docker gallery.

Comment: Interesting choice. Which Docker Application are you referring to since it is rather a developer/enterprise solution. Unfortunately the docker products I looked at aren't free to use (just trialware possible)... but maybe I overlooked s.th.

Comment: @Albin: [Docker for Windows Community Edition (CE)](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) is of course free. Paid versions are either specialized ones or are ripoffs.

Comment: And it uses Hyper-V for virtualizatio,n sounds promising, thanks for suggesting it, I will try it out. Unfortunately it requires Windows 10 to run and it does not run on the Home edition (Pro or Enterprise required) so it doesn't meet the criteria specified in the question.

Comment: @Albin: Question only says "Windows 7+".

Comment: yes but it still doesn't work windows 7. And the "plus" means windows 8 (he specified that in the tags). Anyway I don't want to get hanged up on technicalities just wanted to mention that I case you didn't notice it and because I think it might be relevant for other readers who specifically look for a Win 7/8 solution.

Comment: @Albin: Just last remark for readers: Docker can work without Hyper-V and is available for Windows versions before 10 by installing the desktop [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows).

Comment: yeah, that's right, Hyper-V is optional (although I'm not sure if will be able to stop the drive from spinning up without it)! I was so exited that it's possible to use "real virtualization" (that will be MY main reason for using it) I wasn't clear on that, sorry! I looked into the Docker Toolbox, does it actually give advantage over installing a VirtualBox directly. It doesn't give you more functionality and it's a lot more complicated to set up. If you are able to share any experience I would appreciate it.