# Can you prevent certain applications in Windows 10 from accessing certain drives?

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible in Windows 10 home (maybe through group policies?) to restrict or outright block specific applications from ever accessing specific physical drives?

Comment: See if the following link can help you :https://superuser.com/questions/677114/deny-application-access-to-hard-drive-or-volume-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

(Which version of Windows?)

In the general case, you will need to run the application under a specific user account
and limit its access to the root folder of the disk(s).

For more information see this Microsoft article :
[Access Control Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/access-control).

On Windows Server you may use Group Policies.
See the article
[How to Assign Permissions to Files and Folders through Group Policy](https://www.lepide.com/how-to/assign-permissions-to-files-folders-through-group-policy.html).